# Bulk data upload in Cassandra using Pelops

Tags: cassandra, socketexception, pelops

I am using Pelops to work with Cassandra. I want to insert bulk data using mutator. When i insert around 20000 records it works fine but when I exceed the no of records it shows me a "Connection reset by peer: socket write error". I am writing the following code.

```
Pelops.addPool(CASSANDRA_POOL, new Cluster(CASSANDRA_HOST,
            CASSANDRA_PORT), CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE);
Mutator mutator = Pelops.createMutator(CASSANDRA_POOL);

//writing cols in mutator
mutator.execute(CL_ONE)
```

But it is working for some limited no of records.

I am getting following error:

```
2757 17:42:01,211 DEBUG org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool - Attempting to borrow free connection for node 'localhost'

2757 17:42:01,211 DEBUG org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool - Borrowing connection 'Connection[MyKeyspace][localhost:9160][44937684]'

2977 17:42:01,431 WARN  org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Operand - Operation failed as result of network exception. Connection to node localhost is being marked as corrupt (and will probably be be destroyed). Cause of failure is org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

2977 17:42:01,431 DEBUG org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool - Returned connection 'Connection[MyKeyspace][localhost:9160][44937684]' has been closed or is marked as corrupt

2977 17:42:01,431 DEBUG org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool - Destroying connection 'Connection[MyKeyspace][localhost:9160][44937684]'

Exception in thread "main" org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.exceptions.TransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.exceptions.IExceptionTranslator$ExceptionTranslator.translate(IExceptionTranslator.java:57)
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Operand.tryOperation(Operand.java:115)
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Mutator.execute(Mutator.java:102)
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Mutator.execute(Mutator.java:71)
    at org.brickred.Cassandra.insertData(Cassandra.java:182)
    at org.brickred.Test.main(Test.java:7)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:147)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.flush(TFramedTransport.java:157)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.send_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1020)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1008)
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Mutator$1.execute(Mutator.java:97)
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Mutator$1.execute(Mutator.java:93)
    at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Operand.tryOperation(Operand.java:81)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.write(TIOStreamTransport.java:145)
    ... 10 more
```